# Volley: Create a method that takes care of both JSONArrayRequest and JSONObjectRequest

Tags: java, android, android-volley

Newbie here. 
I'm working on a simple client-server Android app with my friend, trying my best to write the cleanest most beautiful code that I can, strictly following the SOLID principles and using Design Patterns to decouple my classes and components. I wrote this method, hoping that it'll be the only networking code I'll have to write:

```
private void VolleyJSONPostParserRequest(String url, JSONObject requestBody, 
    final Handler handler, final IParser replyParser) {
       JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.POST, url, requestBody, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {    
                try {
                    Object parsedResponse = replyParser.parse(response.toString());
                    notifyObservers(handler, parsedResponse);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG,handler.getClassName() + " reply parsing error!");
                    notifyObservers(handler, null); }
                }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG,"Error receiving response for " + handler.getClassName());
                notifyObservers(handler, null);
                }
                });
        }
```

To my discontent, I found out that sometimes the server's reply will be a JSONObject, and sometimes it will be a JSONArray. I do not want to copy-paste the entire thing and replace "JsonObjectRequest" with "JsonArrayRequest". What's a good solution for this problem? Or is it one of those cases where I'd be better off just copying and pasting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you should implement a custom request (for example, `public class CustomRequest extends Request<NetworkResponse>`). Please read the following Google's training doc for more information:

> [Google Volley - Implementing a Custom Request](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html)

then...

```
@Override
public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        final String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
        // Check if it is JSONObject or JSONArray
        Object json = new JSONTokener(jsonString).nextValue();          
        if (json instanceof JSONObject) {
            //do something...
        } else if (json instanceof JSONArray) {
            //do something...
        } else {
            //do something...
        }
        ...
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: @ranys Hi! You can try with `StringRequest` instead, I think it works too, because in my answer above, `NetworkResponse` is converted to `String`.